# sed convert double quoted csv comma delimited to non quoted pipe delimited

Tags: csv, sed, double-quotes

The input file 'input.file' is:

```
"col one",,,"col, two",,"col, three"
,"col one",,"col, two",,"col, three"
,,"col one","col, two",,"col, three"
```

The desired output file is:

```
col one|||col, two||col, three
|col one||col, two||col, three
||col one|col, two||col, three
```

This is what is in place so far:

```
sed -r 's/"([^"])/\1/g; s/,/|/g'  ./input.file
```

The objective is the first substitution

```
s/"([^"])/\1/g
```

would parse arbitrary fields delineated by " and copy them to the output and  the second substitution

```
s/,/|/g
```

would replace the ',' not included in double quoted fields with '|'.

Comment: is a perl solution okay?

Comment: I am not up to speed on perl. Can you provide it?

Comment: No. The 'col' reference should be xxx. It could be abc, or xyz, etc. The only comma that should remain are those that are within a double quoted string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
"col one",,,"col, two",,"col, three"
,"col one",,"col, two",,"col, three"
,,"col one","col, two",,"col, three"

$ perl -pe 's/"[^"]+"(*SKIP)(*F)|,/|/g; s/"//g' ip.txt
col one|||col, two||col, three
|col one||col, two||col, three
||col one|col, two||col, three
```

- `"[^"]+"(*SKIP)(*F)` skip the pattern `"[^"]+"` and look for any other alternate match provided

  - `(*F)` is short-form for `(*FAIL)` and `(?!)` can also be used instead
- `|,` alternate pattern to match `,`
- `|/g` replace all `,` with `|`
- `s/"//g` then delete all `"`

**Further Reading:**

- [perldoc - regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
- [Using (*SKIP)(*FAIL) to Exclude Unwanted Matches](http://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html#skipfail)

Comment: This works well. Most of the syntax is documented. However the (*SKIP) and (?!) are not. Can you provide documentation reference.

Comment: Follow up: This is working well. A new situation has arisen where there is a \A line feed character within the "...|a" string. Is there a way to remove control characters from within double quoted strings?

Comment: @dansawyer, try `perl -pe 's/"[^"]+"/$& =~ s|pattern|replace|gr/ge' ip.txt` ... what this is doing is within all quoted strings, it is changing `pattern` to `replace`... so for your case, `replace` would be empty and `pattern` would be whatever control characters you need to delete